# Nginx rewrite error with including files in index.php

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, nginx, relative-path

I had an apache webserver where I justed a htaccess. I switched to NGINX and I did the NGINX configuration. My rewrite is as followed:

```
location /mvc/public {
     index index.php;

     try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
 }

location @rewrite{
     rewrite ^/mvc/public/(.*)$ /mvc/public/index.php?url=$1;
}
```

This works properly but now the other files I want include in mine index file like the css and some other scripts give an error.

The error I get is:

```
GET "example.com"/mvc/public/javascript/show/css/bootstrap.min.css 
GET "example.com"/mvc/public/javascript/show/css/simple-sidebar.css
GET "example.com"/mvc/public/javascript/show/css/custom.css 
GET "example.com"/mvc/public/javascript/show/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

When I go to "example.com"/mvc/public/javascript/show/examplecode. The right path to the css is "example.com"/mvc/public/css and the js is "example.com"/mvc/public/js

The HTACCESS I used in Apache was:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So my question is how do I get this working and what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a rewrite issue at all. This looks like your page has relative URLs in its links. When you go to:

```
/mvc/public/javascript/show/examplecode
```

The relative URL base is `/mvc/public/javascript/show/` so when you have css like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
```

(note there is no leading `/` in the href)

the relative URL gets appeneded to the end of the base, making it:

```
/mvc/public/javascript/show/css/custom.css
```

So you either need to change your links to all be absolute URLs or add a base in the page's header (inside the `<head></head>`):

```
<base href="/mvc/public/" />
```